# multiple sub_filter rules for a reverse proxy on nginx?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rewrite

with no evil plans I am trying to mirror a site under other domain, while changing a few strings on the fly.

I set up nginx on a new host to serve as a RP to the master site.
This allows to set one rule of replacement:

```
sub_filter      Originalstring  'new string';
sub_filter_once off;
```

However, I'd like to have several rules running, which [sub_filter allows only one per location](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSubModule).

What can be a solution here, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

now you can upgrade nginx to 1.9.4

```
*) Feature: multiple "sub_filter" directives can be used simultaneously.
```

see full change log here: http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES

Answer (score 7):

Unlike the previous one, the current version of nginx allows to create multiple sub filter rules under one location directive. Like so

```
location / {
   resolver   8.8.8.8;
   proxy_pass http://original-domain.com;
   proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
   proxy_set_header Host original-domain.com;

   subs_filter_types text/css text/xml text/css;
   subs_filter a.original-domain.com b.mydomain.com;
   subs_filter http://$host https://$host;
}
```

You can add up to 255 filters. See http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSubsModule

Make sure you have `subs_filter` installed with nginx by running this command `nginx -V`. Look for `--with-http_sub_module` in the output.

Comment: Are you using the built in ngx_http_sub_module (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) or the 3rd party plugin http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSubsModule?

Comment: I'm using the built-in module. You can check your nginx's error.log file to figure out more about the error in your code.

Comment: `subs_filter` does not support compressed responses, while `sub_filter` does, if coupled with `gunzip on;`

Comment: @mrgamer when you add `proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";`, the response from original server should be without any encoding. So, `subs_filter` should work everywhere when this rule added.

Comment: `"should"` being the most important word here. Sometimes old/proprietary systems behave in non-standard ways. Anyway in NGINX 1.9.4 you can use multiple `sub_filter`, so there is not any reason left to use that submodule

Answer (score 2):

Check [HttpSubsModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSubsModule) module instead. Excerpt from documentation:

> Several substitution rules per location can be specified

Comment: Thanks, AlexD,
I am aware of the HttpSubsModule, which is not installed on the shared hosting, I am trying to implement the feature at.
Looking for a possible hack or a workaround for the available HttpSubModule.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may setup several locations or server_names with one `sub_filter` per earch and proxy the request through them.